# Not able to access sqlite database from alarm service

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I want to access my sqlite database from alarm service.Also wanna add new records to database.I tried a lot but getting exception. Please help me guys..You  can find the entire code below

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service  {

DatabaseManager database;

    String ename;
    int id;
    DateFormat d;
    RestClient obj;
    private Context context;
    Long timstpAtFive;
    private String posturl = "http://infinitsolutions.in/attendance/api/attendance";

    public MyAlarmService(){}

    public MyAlarmService(Context context, Long tlong ){
        this.context = context;
        this.timstpAtFive=tlong;



    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
            d = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            obj = new RestClient((android.app.Activity) context);
            try {

                String stat = "signed in";
                ArrayList<DataRecord>autoList = database.executeQuery("select employee_Id from attendance where date='" + d.format(new Date()) + "' and status = '" + stat + "'");

                int size = autoList.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                          id = autoList.get(i).getInt("employee_Id");
        ArrayList<DataRecord> list = database.executeQuery("select status from attendance where employee_Id ='" + id + "'and date='" + d.format(new Date()) + "'");
                        int n = list.size();
                        if (list.get(n - 1).equals("signed in")) {

                        ArrayList<DataRecord> list1 = database.executeQuery("select employee_name from employee where employee_Id ='" + id + "'");
                        ename = list1.get(0).getString("employee_name");
                        methodemployee(id, ename);

                    }
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 private void methodemployee(int employee_id,String employee_name)
    {
        DataRecord data= new DataRecord();
        try {
            data.put("employee_name", employee_name);
            data.put("employee_Id",employee_id);
            data.put("date", d.format(new Date()));
            data.put("time",timstpAtFive);
            data.put("status", "signed out");
            data.put("type", "auto");
            database.addRecord("attendance", null, data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ArrayList<DataRecord> attendance = database.executeQuery("select * from attendance where employee_Id ='" + employee_id + "'");
        int n=attendance.size();
        //postdata(attendance.get(n-1));

    }




    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    // Post data to server and return acknowledgement from server
    private void postdata(DataRecord dataRecord) {
        obj.POST(posturl, getJSON(dataRecord), new RestListenerJson() {
            @Override
            public void onResultJsonFormat(JSONObject jsonobject) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResultJsonFormat(String jsonobject) {
                String result = jsonobject;

            }
        });
    }
    //Convert the datarecords to JSONString
    private String getJSON(DataRecord dataRecord)

    {
        JSONObject Jobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            DateFormat d1 = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
            //long time = d1.parse(dataRecord.getString("time")).getTime() / 1000;


            Jobj.put("date", dataRecord.getString("date"));
            Jobj.put("employee_Id", dataRecord.getString("employee_Id"));
            Jobj.put("time", timstpAtFive);
            Jobj.put("status", dataRecord.getString("status"));
            Jobj.put("employee_name", dataRecord.getString("employee_name"));
            Jobj.put("type", dataRecord.getString("type"));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //catch (ParseException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Jobj.toString();
    }



}
```

You can find the logcat warning below..there is no error

```
9-21 11:32:00.877    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 11:32:00.877    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication.MyAlarmService.onStart(MyAlarmService.java:74)
09-21 11:32:00.877    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
09-21 11:32:00.877    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2797)
09-21 11:32:00.877    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:145)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:814)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630)
09-21 11:32:00.887    4778-4778/com.example.infinitdeveloper.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how you get the context? and what the exception? post your logcat

Comment: kindly post your variable database declaration line and your log information. so that I can able to find the bug.

Comment: database.executequery("  "); returns cursor how could you initialize to ArrayList

Comment: why you are casting context to Activity `obj = new RestClient((android.app.Activity) context);`

Comment: That context is for posting data to server

Answer (score 0):

You need to get context from Alarm Manager and pass it to the Database Manager class to access Database.

**Edit**
You cannot simply execute database query without initializing. You need to make seprate Database Manager Class. Write your function in it then pass context to that function and get result from database.

Kindly see this link: [Vogella Android Database](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). You are not initializing and opening Database intstant. You need some reading about Android Database.

Comment: Tanx for the response..Can you please post the code for this